# Why can't I use Enumerable.OrderBy on this collection?

Tags: .net, linq

I was hoping to use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) on a [SPFolderCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfoldercollection.aspx) object but after I include System.Linq, OrderBy still does not come up in intellisense.

According to the Documentation, SPFolderCollectionClass inherits from [SPBaseCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasecollection.aspx) which uses IEnumerable.  I thought this was all that I needed, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the LINQ methods require an `IEnumerable<T>`, use the `Enumerable.Cast` method to convert it.

So `x.Cast<SPFolder>().OrderBy(whatever)`.

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy will appear only on a IEnumerable<T> generic class. IEnumerable is different from IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mixed up [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface and [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345746.aspx) class